# Why can't SSH tunneling be used for SIP VOIP encryption?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, voip, sip

On http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page_id=2716 it says "Note that SSH tunneling is not a viable method for VoIP media path encryption."  Why can't SSH tunneling (as opposed to a VPN) be used for VOIP encryption when using unsecure VOIP protocols (such as regular SIP)?

Comment: It says *not viable* - it doesn't say that it *can't*. Probably something about latency causing jitter

Answer (score 3):

SSH protocol run on top of TCP part of the TCP/IP stack.
SIP or other type of voip generally runs on top of UDP protocol.

One of the significant differences between TCP and UDP is that TCP (somewhat) guarantees the delivery of each packet. UDP on the other hand does not. It is fire-and-forget.
The consequence of that if there's some network hiccup TCP will stall and try to resend missing/corrupted packets. With UDP they will be simply lost.

When you apply it to VOIP, a missing UDP packet turns into just a garbled word by the caller. A missing TCP packet becomes inconsistent and annoying delays, still garbled words, and other interferences during a call.

In applications where some packet loss is not critical, such as voip or streaming music or certain types of streaming video or some other real-time related applications, UDP is perfectly acceptable and TCP provides unnecessary overhead and complications.

SSH protocol expects a lossless connection because for it each packet is critical to ensure the integrity of the data encrypted inside of SSH connection.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can only guess at the authors intent and target audience (and bear in mind that was written in over 5 years ago now).   I'd posit that the issue is that SSH is designed to handle TCP streams rather then UDP.

Although I have found reference to [tunneling UDP over SSH](http://www.qcnetwork.com/vince/doc/divers/udp_over_ssh_tunnel.html) it appears to be a more complex hack - probably not something ideal for a VOIP network.  Similarly, while some VPN's (OpenVPN for example) can create TCP tunnels, I think you will find most prefer UDP tunnels as they are more tolerant of packet loss.

Looking at the ch[aracteristics of a TCP vs UDP tunnel,](http://torguard.net/blog/openvpn-service-udp-vs-tcp-which-is-better/) if a UDP tunnel looses a packet it doesn't care, it drops it and expects the encapsulated stream (if its TCP) or application (if its UDP) to handle it.  A TCP tunnel would try and resend the packet, which could have the impact of suddenly and highly increasing the jitter of the connection, making a VOIP connection very unhappy - particularly if the endpoints are far away.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that SSH tunneling is not a viable method for VoIP **media path** encryption.

Emphasis mine.

The media stream is typically negotiated during a SIP call using [Session Description Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol) often as a bidirectional audio stream using the [Real-time Transport Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol).

From the wikipedia article for RTP:

> The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP), although standardized for RTP use, is not normally used in RTP applications because TCP favors reliability over timeliness. Instead the majority of the RTP implementations are built on the User Datagram Protocol (UDP).

The other answers about the differences between UDP and TCP do apply (especially trying to UDP tunnel over SSH), but aren't as significant to SIP as they are to RTP. SIP is perfectly capable of running on top of TCP (and even SCTP). The latency and/or retransmissions of the network may either be handled by the transport protocol (TCP/SCTP) or, in cases where those functions are not provided at the transport layer (UDP), SIP has its own mechanisms for retransmissions and timeouts.

You may, however, run into problems routing SIP over TCP tunneling via SSH as well. This is for similar reasons why SIP traversing a NAT is not very easy. Many headers in SIP and SDP bodies include relevant IP addresses, which you may be implicitly obscuring at the tunnel. Application layer gateways typically handle this in NAT scenarios.

In fact, if you're not careful, you may end up tunneling SIP over SSH without tunneling the RTP at all!